# When i use target SDK 26 then my application is crashed or close in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-injection

When I use target SDK 26 then my application is crashed or close in mobile.
Earlier when I used targetSdkVersion 21 and  compileSdkVersion 21, the application was running fine when I did targetSdkVersion 26 and  compileSdkVersion 26 then  my application was shutting down

**My build.gradle code**

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "purehd.record.pro"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
dependencies{
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+' 
implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0' 
implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6' implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' 
}
```

Error is this

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not
>   support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false,
>   windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false,
>   windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false

please solve this problem

Comment: post your error as well

Comment: Earlier when I used targetSdkVersion 21 and compileSdkVersion 21, the application was running fine when I did targetSdkVersion 26 and compileSdkVersion 26 then my application was shutting down

Comment: any logcat messages?

Comment: post your logcat messages

Comment: sir logcat message too long

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }

Answer (score 1):

keep `windowActionBar` to `false` and add `windowNoTitle` as well and set it to true.

ie

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Change

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
```

Comment: Sir, I did this even though Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar I am having problems

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "purehd.record.pro"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

Comment: got 17 error error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Comment: error: incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to SettingsActivity

Comment: when i change implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'

Comment: Please Solve my problem